# How to insert a null value with Qt?

Tags: c++, sql, qt, null

Tip me plase, how to insert a null value into table using Trolltech Qt 4.x SQL classes? `QSqlQuery`, I guess, or something else from QtNetwork.
As analog of it, in .NET there is the `System.DbNull` class, which represents sql NULL.

And what type should I use for some object's property, that can hold both null-value and `QString`? In C# I could use `System.Object`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From `QSqlQuery::addBindValue` documentation:

> To bind a NULL value, use a null
>   QVariant; for example, use
>   QVariant(QVariant::String) if you are
>   binding a string.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, just what I was looking for !! For those who need it for other datatypes, just use QVariant(QVariant::Date) and so on. (happy to get rid of all the "0000-00-00" values in my database now :-) )

Comment: I find the qt6 doc, generally it's same but it suggests to use `QMetaType::fromType<QString>()` instead of `QVariant::String`, why?

Comment: With `QVariant(QVariant::Date)`, got error `[ODBC SQL Server Driver]Optional feature not implemented`

Answer (score 1):

Answering the second question, `QString` can be null.

Answer (score 0):

The question is for QT 4, but I think it's worth mentioning that in QT 5 you have only to pass a NULL value.

Comment: Can you clarify? How exactly does this work? Could you give a code example? If I put the text "NULL", then it writes the literal string NULL. If I specify NULL (without quotes) then I get the error message "conversion from 'long' to 'const QVariant' is ambiguous".

Comment: @Dan I think it's clear without code, you can pass `NULL` pointer, not the string `"NULL"`. I do not use QT now, but for what I remember you can pass a `NULL` in Qt 5, as I specified in the answer. Do yu have Qt 5 or a precedent version?

Comment: It's not clear without code or else I wouldn't have asked for clarification. In fact your suggestion of nullptr fails to compile in QT 5 with error "conversion from 'nullptr_t' to 'const QVariant' is ambiguous". Using a literal 0 will write a zero into the database, not NULL.